# Trying to find a formally correct way for a proof using shadow and shade of sets

Tags: combinatorics

> Let
>
> - $|S| = n, \mathcal{A} \subseteq \binom{S}{k}, 1 \leq k < n$.
> - $\nabla \mathcal{A} := \left\{A \in \binom{S}{k+1} : \exists A' \in \mathcal{A} \text{ so } A' \subset A\right\}$ (shade of $\mathcal{A}$)
> - $\Delta \mathcal{A} := \left\{A \in \binom{S}{k-1} : \exists A' \in \mathcal{A} \text{ so } A \subset A'\right\}$ (shadow of $\mathcal{A}$)
>
> Show that $\mathcal{A} = \nabla\Delta\mathcal{A} \Rightarrow \mathcal{A} = \binom{S}{k}$applies for $\mathcal{A} \neq \emptyset$

This seems pretty obvious to me. If I build a set $X$ by successively each item of all items of $\mathcal{A}$ (shadow), and afterwards add each possible item to each item of $X$, I (re-) create at least all items of $\mathcal{A}$, and more of them unless $\mathcal{A}$ already contains all possible items.

I played around for some time, but am struggling with a *formally correct* way to prove this.

Can you please tell me how a formally correct approach could be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\emptyset \neq \mathcal{A} \neq \binom{S}{k}$. Then there is some $B:= \{x_1,...,x_k\} \subseteq S$ such that $B \not \in \mathcal{A}$ and some $z \in S \setminus B$ such that for $C:=\{x_1,...,x_{k-1},z\}$ we have $C \in \mathcal{A}$. You can prove this statement as follows:

Assume that for all sets $B = \{x_1,...,x_k\} \subseteq S$ and all sets $C:= \{x_1,...,x_{k-1},z\}$ with $z \in S\setminus B$, we have both $B \in \mathcal{A}$ and $C \in \mathcal{A}$. Now assume that we have two sets $D,E \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $D = \{y_1,..,y_{k-i},y_{k-i+1},...,y_k\}$ and $E = \{y_1,...,y_{k-i},v_{k-i+1},...,v_k\}$ where all $v_j \in S \setminus D$ and $1 \leq i < k$. The sets $D$ and $E$ differ by exactly $i$ elements. By an application of the assumption about all $B,C$ above, we get that every $F = \{y_1,...,y_{k-i-1},z,v_{k-i+1},...,v_k\}$ with $z \in S \setminus E$ is also in $\mathcal{A}$, particularly those $F$ with $z \neq y_{k-i}$. In other words, every set in $\binom{S}{k}$ that differs from $D$ by exactly $i+1$ elements is also in $\mathcal{A}$. Thus given our assumption about $B,C$ we find by induction that all sets $Y\in \binom{S}{k}$ that differ from some $X \in \mathcal{A}$ by at least $1$ and at most $k$ elements are also in $\mathcal{A}$, and so $\mathcal{A} = \binom{S}{k}$. Since this contradicts the assumption that $\mathcal{A}\neq \binom{S}{k}$, we have shown that there is some $B$ such that there is some $C$ as above such that $C \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \not \in \mathcal{A}$.

Now back to our original problem: we just showed that we can choose $B$ and $C$ as we did in the very beginning, and so $\{x_1,...,x_{k-1}\} \in \Delta\mathcal{A}$ and thus $B \in \nabla\Delta\mathcal{A}$ and so $\mathcal{A} \neq \nabla \Delta \mathcal{A}$. Taking the contrapositive gives you the claim.

(I think a similar argument shows the same for $\Delta \nabla \mathcal{A}$.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you mean $C := \{x_1,\cdots,x_{k-1},z\}$? If not, what are your $c_i$?

Comment: @muffel Thanks, that was a typo, I do mean $C:= \{x_1,...,x_{k-1},z\}$.

Comment: @muffel Be sure to prove the claim that ends in "(why?)", that's a necessary part of this proof.

Comment: I thought of the 'why' by building it the other way round: The $C$ could be built by taking an element of $\mathcal{A}$ so that by exchanging one item of it, the resulting set is not in $\mathcal{A}$ (and therefore the $B$ of your example). As $\mathcal{A} \neq \binom{S}{k}$ such an element must exists. Am I right? Is there a shorter or better way to assume such a $C$ exists?

Comment: @muffel: That's not actually a proof, that's just a reaffirmation of the claim. I added a proof to my answer. You wouldn't usually add a proof in the middle of another proof, you would first give the proof for the claim "if $\emptyset \neq \mathcal{A} \neq \binom{S}{k}$, then there is some $B := ...$ such that $B \not \in \mathcal{A}$ and some $z...$ such that for $C...$ we have $C \in \mathcal{A}$. Proof:..." and then you would use that lemma to prove what you actually want to prove.

Comment: I don't really understand your proof: Why do you assume $B \in \mathcal{A}$? Shouldn't you just assume that no such $B$ and $C$ exist? If $|\mathcal{A}| = 1$, then no $D, E \in \mathcal{A}$ with $D \neq E$ exist (or am I wrong?)

Comment: @muffel The part in the middle is a proof for "if [$\mathcal{A} \neq \emptyset$ and $\forall B = \{x_1,...,x_k\} \in \binom{S}{k} \forall z \in S \setminus B, C = \{x_1,...,x_{k-1},z\}: B \in \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow C \in \mathcal{A}$], then [$\mathcal{A} = \binom{S}{k}$]". The contrapositive of that is "if $\emptyset \neq \mathcal{A} \neq \binom{S}{k}$, then $\exists B = ... \exists C = ...: B\in \mathcal{A} \wedge C \not \in \mathcal{A}$. I can't start out assuming that which I want to prove.

Comment: thank you! That helped me to understand what you're showing. But how are those $D,E$ related to $B,C$ - and what are those $y_i$? Do I need to build a special case for $|\mathcal{A}| = 1$ (see my first comment)? What do yo mean with "By an application of the assumption about all B,C above, we get that every F [...]"

Comment: The idea is that if I assume that for every set $B\in \mathcal{A}$, all sets $C$ that differ from $B$ in exactly $1$ element are also in $\mathcal{A}$, then that suffices to show that all sets that differ from $B$ in up to $k$ elements are also in $\mathcal{A}$. I do this by taking $D, E$ which differ in $i$ elements where $1 \leq i < k$, and then I apply the statement for $B,C$ to $E$ and find that all sets that differ from $E$ in exactly one element are also there, in particular those that differ from $D$ in $i+1$ elements.

Comment: Since $\mathcal{A} \neq \emptyset$, this implies $\mathcal{A} = \binom{S}{k}$. Altogether this shows the statement from my comment an hour ago. I just corrected a typo in the proof as well, the $v_j$ have to be from $S \setminus D$.

Comment: great, thank you, I finally understood it!